# ReqexKitLite regex with @

Tags: objective-c, regex

I need to find strings like "@something" beginning with "@" with RegexKitLite. I've used regex "@[a-z]+", and it works ok. But I need "@" only at the begin of words, so I've tried "\b@[a-z]+" and this time it doesn't work. Any ideas how to make proper regex?

Comment: try this regex:`"\b\s*+@[a-z]+"`. i guess that there can be zero or more spaces between word boundry and @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here

```
(?<=\W|^)@[a-z]+
```

You can see it online [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1hh)

`(?<=\W|^)` is a lookbehind assertion that says, ensure that there is a non word character `\W` or the beginning of the string `^` before the `@`

Comment: Thanks, it works.
And also thanks for resource link: http://regexr.com - usefull regex tool

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative look-behind assertion. E.g. like this:

```
(?<!\s)@[a-z]+
```

That means, \s may not be before the @.

Alex